# How to erase one overlay among two?

Tags: android, android-maps

I have two overlays, one is (ItemizedOverlay) for placing markers on the map and other is (Overlay) for drawing route from source to destination. It's fine in drawing route on map with respect to the changes of markers on the map. But problem is the previously drawn route cannot be erased to draw new route.

I tried `mapView.getOverlays().clear()`. But it is erasing both markers and route.

Is there any possibility get one overlay object among two defined overlays for mapview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapView.getOverlays()` returns a list of `Overlay`s that is being used. You can remove one `Overlay` from that list, leaving the other.

```
Overlay itemizedOverlay, overlay; //you need an instance of the overlays

List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
overlays.remove(itemizedOverlay);
```

Or, if you know the index of your `Overlay` in the list:

```
int myOverlayIndex; //the index of your Overlay in the list

List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
overlays.remove(myOverlayIndex);
```